# Is a cube root ever converted into a 4th root

Tags: roots, radicals

For the following exercises, find functions () and () so the given function can be expressed as ℎ()=(()).

[image]

However, in the book, the answer is:

[image]

I get a similar answer only I don't get the 4th root. I get the same cube root as the question. Does the cube root turn into a 4th root?

Comment: That's definitely a typo.

Comment: It's a typo and it doesn't work.  If $f(x) = \sqrt[4]{x}$ then $f(g(x))= \sqrt[4]{g(x)} =\sqrt[4]{\frac 1{2x-3}} \ne \sqrt[3]{\frac 1{2x-3}}$.

Comment: BTW there are a lot of possible answers  $g(x) = x$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac 1{2x-3}}$ is one. $g(x)=2x-3$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac 1x}$ is another. $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac 1{2x-3}}$ and $f(x) = x$ is another.  $g(x)=(2x-3)^5$ and $f(x) = \sqrt[15]{\frac 1x}$ is yet another.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking I had missed some important concept.